# Notifications sounds not affected by iPad 2 volume

Tags: ipad, notifications, audio

When turn down the volume on my iPad 2 all the way down, It still makes a sound when notifications are received.
Is there any way to globally disable notifications sounds ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **Settings | General | Sounds**, you can either set the sound level of the alerts, or choose that it will be affected by the Volume buttons (which is off by default).

#### Update

In iOS 10 (and maybe earlier versions, I'm not sure when the change happened) this setting is under **Settings | Sounds** and is called *Change with Buttons* in the *Ringer and Alerts* section.